# What does "service not available" mean in Perl's Mail::Sender?

Tags: perl, email

I'm trying to send mails from Perl using the Mail::sender module. But I keep getting -4 return messages. The manual says -4 is service not available. What does that mean?

Comment: Show your short demonstration script which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Service not available" generally means that the server you are trying to contact is not online. In your case it is probably the SMTP-server that is offline.

Comment: ok.If I'm behind a proxy..does the smtp server come after the proxy or before it?

Comment: It's not our network, so we don't know what they've set up for you. You'll have to ask your network provider what you should do.